# Add index to output

Tags: python

I run a model that predicts the classes (0,1) and outputs the disagreements with human ratings. This code works well for me:

```
for input, prediction, label in zip(test_text, test_pred_class[0], test_label):
  if prediction != label:
    print(input, '\n\n', 'has been machine coded as', prediction, 'and should be', label, 'according to human coding.\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

This is my output:

> THIS IS A TEXT...
>
> has been machine coded as 1 and should be 0 according to human
> coding.
>
> ---

I want to add the index number to my output for practical reasons. But I fail to do so.

Adding `input.index` results in some gibberish:

> <built-in method index of str object at 0x7f7b75cd0d50>

I tried adding `prediction.index` / `label.index` but get the error:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'index'

My final output should include a TEXT ID like this:

> Text ID 9
>
> THIS IS A TEXT...
>
> has been machine coded as 1 and should be 0 according to human
> coding.
>
> Text ID 18
>
> THIS IS A TEXT...
>
> has been machine coded as 0 and should be 1 according to human
> coding.
>
> ---
>
> TEXT ID 42
>
> THIS IS A TEXT...
>
> has been machine coded as 1 and should be 0 according to human
> coding.
>
> ---

Can I add enumerate here?

Comment: Are you using input as a function here or a variable name, also another issue is I think index returns function rather than the result of the function call, which seems to be what you want. Do you have an example to try out with your code?

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your quick reply. Input is a variable here including strings and looks like this:

0       a string
                              ...                        
2087    another string
Name: text, Length: 2088, dtype: object

Comment: Is the index number in this case the number preceding the strings in the input variable object?

Comment: Yes, correct. Thus I tried to use input.index. Do you see a way to print the index number with my results?